# "Submit Application to iTunes Connect..." Xcode feature with filename that contain whitespace

Tags: iphone, xcode, whitespace, app-store-connect

Xcode has a nice feature that let you submit your application to iTunes connect without launching Application Loader. The problem appears when you have a whitespace in the application name.

[image: Screenshot]

I understand the problem, but since Xcode is naming the file automatically, how can I use this feature without changing the name of my app?

Thanks,

P.S. I will file a radar if there's no way to do it. I just wanted to be sure that there were no other way.

Comment: I didn't find a way. I did build and archive, renamed the file and submitted it through the app uploader. I hope you manage to find a better workaround!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having spaces in file or folder names is always a very bad idea. In theory things should work but in the end that white space will bite you in the **s.

So the easiest way to fix this is indeed to change your target name.

Just remember that the name of your app on disk (Some App.app) is **not** the same as the name that is shown on the device's home screen. That name you configure through the Info.plist and can be completely different from the app file name.

Comment: Thanks St3fan, that worked.

What you actually need to do is change the Product name value in you build settings of your target and change the "CFBundleDisplayName" in you Info.plist (just rename the target doesn't work).

Comment: With the new SDK (4.2) I can't validate my app with a space in the CFBundleDisplayName key of my info.plist despite my product name containing no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I found a post on the internet that allowed me to get past this issue.
After doing a Build and Archive, go to Organizer and view the build entry under Archived Applications.  Right click on the build and select "Show in Finder".  You will see a file called "ArchiveInfo.plist".  Open this file using the Property List Editor app.  Find the entry in the plist called XCApplicationName and edit the entry to remove spaces.  Save and Close the file and try to Validate/Submit the app.  The error should not show up.
I am not sure what the ramifications of doing it this way, but it did resolve the error.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you VERY much. This is the real answer, guys !

At least until Apple fixes this oold bug.